# How To Use WITH RECURSIVE in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a query but i don't know how to run in Laravel

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_path (id, name, lvl) AS(SELECT id, name, 0 lvl FROM category WHERE parent =1  UNION ALL SELECT c.id, c.name,cp.lvl + 1 FROM category_path AS cp JOIN category AS c ON cp.id = c.parent) SELECT * FROM category_path GROUP BY lvl ORDER BY lvl DESC limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DB::select('your query here');` 
here is official link to doc [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I Think You want to use Raw Query You Can try this:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('your query here'));
```

Comment: Can you show me what You get in response by this method

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE category_path (id, title, lvl) AS ( SELECT id, title, 0 lvl FROM' at line 1 (SQL: WITH RECURSIVE category_path (id, title, lvl) AS ( SELECT id, title, 0 lvl FROM category WHERE parent_id IS NULL UNION ALL SELECT c.id, c.title,cp.lvl + 1 FROM category_path AS cp JOIN category AS c ON cp.id = c.parent_id ) SELECT * FROM category_path ORDER BY lvl)

Comment: Does your query run if executed directly in sql?

Comment: This is a syntax error in your query laravel is executing query perfectly try to run your query in phpmyadmin

Comment: mysql version mismatch